# Subnormal numbers in different precisions with MPFR

Tags: c++, c, floating-point, mpfr, multiprecision

I would like to emulate various *n*-bit binary floating-point formats, each with a specified *e_max* and *e_min*, with *p* bits of precision. I would like these formats to emulate subnormal numbers, faithful to the IEEE-754 standard.

Naturally, my search has lead me to the MPFR library, being IEEE-754 compliant and able to support subnormals with the `mpfr_subnormalize()` function. However, I've ran into some confusion using `mpfr_set_emin()` and `mpfr_set_emax()` to correctly set up a subnormal-enabled environment. I will use IEEE double-precision as an example format, since this is the example used in the MPFR manual:

http://mpfr.loria.fr/mpfr-current/mpfr.html#index-mpfr_005fsubnormalize

```
mpfr_set_default_prec (53);
mpfr_set_emin (-1073); mpfr_set_emax (1024);
```

The above code is from the MPFR manual in the above link - note that neither *e_max* nor *e_min* are equal to the expected values for `double`. Here, *p* is set to 53, as expected of the `double` type, but *e_max* is set to 1024,  rather than the correct value of 1023, and *e_min* is set to -1073; well below the correct value of -1022. I understand that setting the exponent bounds too tightly results in overflow/underflow in intermediate computations in MPFR, but I have found that setting *e_min* exactly is critical for ensuring correct subnormal numbers; too high or too low causes a subnormal MPFR result (updated with `mprf_subnormalize()`) to differ from the corresponding `double` result.

My question is how should one decide which values to pass to `mpfr_set_emax()` and (especially) `mpfr_set_emin()`, in order to guarantee correct subnormal behaviour for a floating-point format with exponent bounds *e_max* and *e_min*? There doesn't seem to be any detailed documentation or discussion on the matter.

With all my thanks,

James.

EDIT 30/07/16: Here is a small program which demonstrates the choice of *e_max* and *e_min* for single-precision numbers.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <float.h>
#include <mpfr.h>

using namespace std;

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    cout.precision(120);

    // IEEE-754 float emin and emax values don't work at all
    //mpfr_set_emin (-126);
    //mpfr_set_emax (127);

    // Not quite
    //mpfr_set_emin (-147);
    //mpfr_set_emax (128);

    // Not quite
    //mpfr_set_emin (-149);
    //mpfr_set_emax (128);

    // These float emin and emax values work in subnormal range
    mpfr_set_emin (-148);
    mpfr_set_emax (128);

    cout << "emin: " << mpfr_get_emin() << "    emax: " << mpfr_get_emax() << endl;

    float f = FLT_MIN;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) f = nextafterf(f, INFINITY);

    mpfr_t m;
    mpfr_init2 (m, 24);
    mpfr_set_flt (m, f, MPFR_RNDN);

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        f = nextafterf(f, 0);
        mpfr_nextbelow(m);
        cout << i << ": float: " << f << endl;
        //cout << i << ":  mpfr: " << mpfr_get_flt (m, MPFR_RNDN) << endl;
        mpfr_subnormalize (m, 1, MPFR_RNDN);
        cout << i << ":  mpfr: " << mpfr_get_flt (m, MPFR_RNDN) << endl;
    }

    mpfr_clear (m);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hmmm, Does _e_min_ reflect `DBL_MIN` (min pos. normal value) or `DBL_TRUE_MIN` (min pos. subnormal value)?

Comment: Off-by-1 issues are common with exponent range specs concerning FP formats.  Depends on the model and signicand format `x.xxx...xxx` or `.xxxx...xxx`.

Comment: I don't follow.  It is unsurprising that the configured *e_min* affects the behavior of `mpfr_subnormalize()`, as for any given small input, that is what determines how many significant bits of precision there will be in the result, and indeed, whether the result is subnormal (from MPFR's perspective) at all.  Why do you suppose that you would set MPFR's exponent bounds to anything different from the bounds applicable to the format you want to use?

Comment: @chux I let *e_min* be the minimum value that the exponent portion of the floating-point format is able to take - e.g. -126, for single-precision floats. 
@John This is what I'm wondering. However, say I emulate single-precision IEEE floats, if I set the MPFR *e_min* to the minimum exponent value for `float` (-126), the MPFR subnormals do not match `float` subnormals. They only match when I set MPFR *e_min* to -148, bizarrely. I assume that the extra lower exponent values are for internal MPFR computation purposes, but, in general, for an *n*-bit format, I don't know what *e_min* should be.

Comment: An answer to this question, courtesy of Vincent Lefèvre, has been given at: https://www.researchgate.net/post/MPFR_In_general_what_should_the_values_of_e_max_and_e_min_be_to_get_correct_subnormal_numbers_in_different_precisions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm copying my answer I gave on ResearchGate (with a link to the `mpfr_subnormalize` documentation):

There are different conventions to express significands and the associated exponents. IEEE 754 chooses to consider significands between 1 and 2, while MPFR (like the C language, see `DBL_MAX_EXP` for instance) chooses to consider significands between 1/2 and 1 (for practical reasons related to multiple precision). For instance, the number 17 is represented as 1.0001·2<sup>4</sup> in IEEE 754 and as 0.10001·2<sup>5</sup> in MPFR. As you can see, this means that exponents are increased by 1 in MPFR compared to IEEE 754, hence e<sub>max</sub> = 1024 instead of 1023 for double precision.

Concerning the choice of e<sub>min</sub> for double precision, one needs to be able to represent 2<sup>−1074</sup> = 0.1·2<sup>−1073</sup>, so that e<sub>min</sub> needs to be at most −1073 (as in MPFR, all numbers are normalized).

As documented, the [`mpfr_subnormalize`](https://www.mpfr.org/mpfr-3.1.4/mpfr.html#index-mpfr_005fsubnormalize) function considers that the subnormal exponent range is from e<sub>min</sub> to e<sub>min</sub> + PREC(x) − 1, so that for instance, you need to set e<sub>min</sub> = −1073 to emulate IEEE double precision.

Comment: Thanks Vincent; that helps a lot. Just to be double sure that I understand, IEEE-754 exponents are offset by +1 in MPFR, and if I were to want a *p*-bit precision floating-point format, with a normalised exponent range lower bound of *e*, and correct subnormals, I would need to `mpfr_set_emin` with *e - (p - 1)*? Cheers.

Comment: @JamesTurner Basically you need to consider the least positive subnormal of the system. If it is 2^e, then you need to call `mpfr_set_emin` with e+1. For instance, for double precision, the least positive subnormal is 2^(−1022−53+1) = 2^(−1074), so that you need to call `mpfr_set_emin` with −1074+1 = −1073. That's emin−p+1 with emin expressed in the MPFR/C convention, or emin−p+2 with emin expressed in the IEEE-754 binary convention.